# How to get Youtube Channel Subscriber count with Youtube Data API v3

Tags: java, youtube

I use Eclipse Kepler with Youtube Data Api v3.

I am trying to get number of subscribers of a channel using:

```
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.getStatistics().getSubscriberCount();
```

But it seems to be the wrong way go get this information.

Can someone tell me how to get the channel subscriber count?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the right client library. This example is based on YouTube Data API v3

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev125-1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**SubscriberCount.java**

```
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    }
};

YouTube youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), httpRequestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("<Your-Application-Name>")
        .build();
YouTube.Channels.List search = youTube.channels().list("statistics");
search.setForUsername("codeherenow");
search.setKey("<Insert-API-Key>");
ChannelListResponse response = search.execute();

List<Channel> channels = response.getItems();
for (Channel channel : channels) {
    System.out.println(channel.getStatistics().getSubscriberCount());
}
```